# NameError: name 'output' is not defined

Tags: python

I've just started learning python and was writing a (seemingly) simple program but encountered the "name not defined" error.

This is my code:

```
if iDisL == cDisL or iDisL == cDisR:
    output = iDisL

if iDisR == cDisL or iDisR == cDisR:
    output = iDisR

oFile = open("manout.txt", "w")
oFile.write(output)
```

The strange thing is this worked the first time when running, but did not when I plugged in a new set of numbers into my input file. I am running python 3.

Comment: Well, what happens if neither one of your two `if` statements is executed?

Comment: Variables spring into existence through magic the first time you assign them a value. If you never do that, they don't exist.

Comment: Try adding a `print` statement in both `if` statements and let us know which `if` works.

Comment: You might also have a problem if both conditions are true, depending on what your expected output is in that case (`iDisL` or `iDisR`). If you expect exactly one of them to be true, you need to handle the other cases (i.e. neither or both) as errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both `(iDisL == cDisL or iDisL == cDisR)` and `(iDisR == cDisL or iDisR == cDisR)` are `False`, output is not defined. Note that.

About [NameError](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/exceptions.html#NameError):

> it's raised when a local or global name is not found.

Answer (score 2):

The [`NameError`](https://kite.com/python/docs/exceptions.NameError)exception occurs when code tries to access a variable that hasn't been assigned yet.

I would suggest you to define default value for cases when `iDisL` and `iDisR` are not equal to `cDisL` and `cDisR`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to solve your problem:

```
output = ""

if iDisL == cDisL or iDisL == cDisR:
    output = iDisL

if iDisR == cDisL or iDisR == cDisR:
    output = iDisR

oFile = open("manout.txt", "w")
oFile.write(output)
```

Or check if output is "" and don't write the file.